# Method Call Expected... Why?

Tags: java, variance

In this code here, I have a text file that reads the numbers placed inside of it, and then the variance is calculated. One problem is that my last piece of code `return nSumVar();` says that I need to create a method, but my nsumvar is already initialized so what is the problem?

```
public double getVariance()
{
    boolean done = false;
    int nCount = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < maxArr; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < maxArr; j++){

            // ------------------------------------------
            // If the array entry is valid then add it to total
            // If not then exit the loops and return the total
            //
            if (a[i][j] != INVALID)
            {
                nVarianceAray[i][j] = a[i][j] - mean;
                nVarianceAray[i][j] *= nVarianceAray[i][j];
                nCount ++;
            }
            else
            {
                done = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (done == true) {
            break;
        }
    }

    int nSumVar = 0;
    done = false;

    for (int i=0; i<maxArr; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; i<maxArr; j++)
        {

            {
                nSumVar += nVarianceAray[i][j];
            }

            {
                done = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(done)
            break;
        nSumVar/=nCount;
    }
    return nSumVar();
}}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `()`. They are not supposed to be there!

Comment: `nSumVar` is a variable - not a method, the `()` that comes after it are used when you're calling a method, you should simply `return nSumVar;` as the comment above suggests.

Comment: nSumVar() calls a function you want to return the variable

Comment: ohh thank you guys i appreciate it, i cant believe i missed something so dumb haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In above code *getVariance()* method returns a double so *getVariance* method should return a double value. Also in your code *nSumVar* declared as an *int* variable not a method. 
Correct call is 
`return nSumVar` 
not <strike>`return nSumVar()`</strike>.